# Adjust SNOPT iteration limit from PyDrake

Tags: python, drake

How can I adjust the SNOPT iteration limit from PyDrake?

I have tried:

```
mp = MathematicalProgram()

mp.SetSolverOption(SolverType.kSnopt, "Iterations limit", 100000)
```

but this does not seem to have done anything.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want "Major iterations limit".  Please reference the SNOPT solver options from p63 of http://www.ccom.ucsd.edu/~peg/papers/sndoc7.pdf.

Comment: It looks like the default value for Major iterations limit is 100. I tried increasing it with 
    mp.SetSolverOption(SolverType.kSnopt, "Major iterations limit", 10000000) 
but saw no change in the output. 

Does this indicate that I might actually be using a solver other than SNOPT? I also tried adjusting the parameter as if it were IPOPT with 
    mp.SetSolverOption(SolverType.kIpopt, "max_iter", 30000) 
and still saw no improvement.

Comment: To see what solver you used (after calling mp.Solve()), you can use print mp.GetSolverId()

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you are sure that you are using Snopt, then you do

```
mp.SetSolverOption(SolverType.kSnopt, "Print file", PRINT_FILE_NAME)
```

you should see an output file with name PRINT_FILE_NAME, and it shows the information in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example that worked for me:

```
import pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram as mp
from pydrake.solvers.snopt import SnoptSolver

prog = mp.MathematicalProgram()
# Add your problem-specific stuff to prog...

solver_options = mp.SolverOptions()
solver_options.SetOption(SnoptSolver.id(), "Major iterations limit", 10)

result = mp.Solve(prog, solver_options=solver_options)
print(f"Solver: {result.get_solver_id().name()}\n")
```

The print statement at the end should output `Solver: SNOPT/fortran` if you are indeed using SNOPT.

Note there is also a "Minor iterations limit" that you can set in the same way, as Russ suggested have a look at Section 7.7 of the [SNOPT documentation](https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/guides/sndoc7.pdf) for more detailed info on these settings.